# How to set value in Jquery Clone while generating dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, clone

I am using clone to generate dynamic HTML on click of button ,
following is my HTML for the same.

```
<input id="AddPhoneType" onclick="setEmailValues()" value="Gen Email"  type="button">

<div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="ExtAddEmailTemplate" id="ExtAddEmailTemplate">

<input name="RemoveEmail"  class="RemovePhoneBtn" value="-" id="RemoveEmail" type="button">
<input type="text" name="txtExtEmail" class="ExtEmailClass" value=""  placeholder="Email" /></div>

<div id="EmailContainer">  </div>
```

And following is the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#AddExtEmail').click(function () {
                $('<div/>', {
                    'class': 'ExtAddEmail', html: GetHtmlForEmail()
                }).hide().appendTo('#EmailContainer').slideDown('slow');
            });
    });

    function setEmailValues() {

               $('<div/>', {
                    'class': 'ExtAddEmail', html: GetHtmlForEmail()
                }).hide().appendTo('#EmailContainer').slideDown('slow');
        }

function GetHtmlForEmail()
        {
            var len = $('.ExtAddEmail').length;

           var emailValue = 'oner@one.com,twor@two.com';
            var emaiArray = emailValue.split(","); 


            var $html = $('.ExtAddEmailTemplate').clone();
            $html.find('[name=txtExtEmail]')[0].name = "txtExtEmail" + len;


            return $html.html();
        }
```

Now on click of button I need to generate 2 text box let say with respective email ID let say "oner@one.com", "twor@two.com"

Now my issue is that I am not able to set the value while generating the HTML
I have tried following

> $html.find('[type=text]')[0].val('oner@one.com');
>   Have try finding using class , text etc. but was not able to set the value.

I also need to set value of dropdown , assuming that if I may able to set value of text box, will able to it do for dropdown also.

I am able to do it after HTML getting generated

```
 $('#EmailContainer .ExtEmailClass').each(function () {
       this.value = 'oner@one.com';
   });
```

But I think if we can set value while generating HTML is most appropriate solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code it is working perfectly,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tring Reset</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="AddPhoneType" onclick="setEmailValues()" value="Gen Email"  type="button">

<div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="ExtAddEmailTemplate" id="ExtAddEmailTemplate">

<input name="RemoveEmail"  class="RemovePhoneBtn" value="-" id="RemoveEmail" type="button">
<input type="text" name="txtExtEmail" class="ExtEmailClass" placeholder="Email" /></div>
<input type="button" id="AddExtEmail" value="+"/>
<div id="EmailContainer">  </div> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#AddExtEmail').click(function () {
                 $('<div/>', {
                     'class': 'ExtAddEmail', html: GetHtmlForEmail()
                 }).hide().appendTo('#EmailContainer').slideDown('slow');
             });
     });

     function setEmailValues() {

                $('<div/>', {
                     'class': 'ExtAddEmail', html: GetHtmlForEmail()
                 }).hide().appendTo('#EmailContainer').slideDown('slow');
         }

 function GetHtmlForEmail()
         {
             var len = $('.ExtAddEmail').length;

            var emailValue = 'oner@one.com,twor@two.com';
             var emaiArray = emailValue.split(","); 


             var $tryiy = $('.ExtAddEmailTemplate').clone();
             $tryiy.find('[name=txtExtEmail]')[0].name = "txtExtEmail" + len;
             $tryiy.find('[name=txtExtEmail'+len+']').attr("value",emaiArray[0]);

             return $tryiy.html();
         }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have set the value using the `attr("value",emaiArray[0]);` property of the element using jquery and it is working fine

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, can you please also suggest solution for selecting dropdow, too :), I am trying to do ,Thanks > $html.find('[id=<%= ddlPhontType.ClientID %>' + len + ']')

Comment: Is this part <%= ddlPhontType.ClientID %> getting passed into the id attribute?